# DELETED WINDOWS NO BACKUP; LOCKED OUT OF UBUNTU ACCOUNT

Tags: dual-boot, root, 15.10, windows-10

I recently tried to dual-boot windows 10 and Ubuntu 15.10. I accidentally deleted all windows files in the process, with no backup. now, I can't get into my Ubuntu account because I had no password! HELP!!!!

Comment: you may be able to recover some files using testdisk http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

As quoted by the official Ubuntu LostPassword documentation, do the following to login to Ubuntu:

1. Reboot your computer.
2. Hold Shift during boot to start GRUB menu.
3. Highlight your image and press E to edit.
4. Find the line starting with "linux" and append rw init=/bin/bash at the end of that line.
5. Press Ctrl + X to boot.
6. Type in passwd .
7. Set your password.

As for the windows, I would recomend contacting microsoft to get your license back.  Also, if you have a windows recovery partition, you can boot off of that and re-install windows.
Best of luck!